# Mousewheel event and Jquery Draggable Div

Tags: jquery, draggable, mousewheel

I am developing a custom scroll bar that needs a mouse wheel event. Here is the jquery draggable method attached to the scroll bars.

```
 $(this._ScrollBarTrackPiece).draggable({
          axis: 'y',
          containment: "parent",
          start: function(event,ui){
            this.previousPosition = ui.position;
          }.bind(this),
          drag: function(event,ui) {
            if(this.previousPosition.top > ui.position.top){
                this.doVerticalStepScroll(this._crosstabScrollBarEventConstants.Up);
            } else{
                this.doVerticalStepScroll(this._crosstabScrollBarEventConstants.Down);
            }
          }.bind(this)
    });
```

However, I need to hook up a mouse wheel event to do the exact same thing as the jquery method. I don't know where to start as I wish it was as simple as binding the wheel event to the jquery draggable method and determining if its up or down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below to have a mouse wheel event

```js
//FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";

if (this._ScrollBarTrackPiece.attachEvent) //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting)
    this._ScrollBarTrackPiece.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, doScroll);
else if (this._ScrollBarTrackPiece.addEventListener) //WC3 browsers
    slideshow.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, doScroll, false);

var doScroll = function()
{ ... }
```

Thank you,